# collection.find "fields" option interfere with "selector" argument

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I'd like to publish online users list to my clients, and exclude all but 'username' properties due to security reasons. I have following server side publish:

```
Meteor.publish 'onlineUsers', ->
    users = Meteor.users.find
        "services.resume.loginTokens.0":
            $exists: true
```

And it works just fine, producing following output:

```
console.log users.fetch()

>> [{ 
       id: 'kFney2anhwZC4w4zX',
       createdAt: Fri Jan 31 2014 20:04:40 GMT+0400 (MSK),
       <...>
   }, 
   {   _id: 'tLNbhoqCex46v5L7s',
       createdAt: Fri Jan 31 2014 20:05:04 GMT+0400 (MSK),
       ...
   }]
```

But as I add "fields" option to publish arguments, result is an empty list:

```
Meteor.publish 'onlineUsers', ->
    users = Meteor.users.find
        "services.resume.loginTokens.0":
            $exists: true
        fields:
            username: true

    console.log users.fetch()

>> []
```

So the questions are:

1. Does the "find" method query only fields included to result cursor?
2. If it's so, what is the best practice to publish subset of fields for each user?

**upd:**
As Andrew Mao noticed, I had a mistake while using CoffeeScript syntax. Without a preceeding comma my `fields` option was a part of first argument object. The correct method call should be following:

```
Meteor.users.find
    "services.resume.loginTokens.0":
        $exists: true
    , 
        fields:
            username: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Coffeescript and making a mistake with its syntax. `fields` needs to be a key in the second argument to `find`, not the first one. One way you can write it is

```
Meteor.publish 'onlineUsers', ->
    users = Meteor.users.find {"services.resume.loginTokens.0": {$exists: true}},
        { fields:
            { username: true }
        }
```

All the curly braces are actually optional above, and just used to show the structure. You can omit them once you become more familiar with coffeescript. But that all-important comma has to be between your arguments somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew! You're absolutely right. Inserting a line with a comma before `fields` and adding intend to it fixed the problem.

Comment: ughh, that coffeescript. I was scared it is a bug in livedata :)

Comment: @imslavko Coffeescript is just a quicker way to write javascript. Great for shooting oneself in the foot, though.